# Can I make php run shell scripts?

Tags: php, shell

What I want to do is create a small webpage with 3 links when a particular link is clicked it runs a particular ssh script through console

for example if I wanted to make "STOP" and when it's clicked it would go to a ssh script...say stop.sh and that would just have stop in it, this would stop the server.

Is their an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can run. Following methods allows your to run commands in shell

1. [shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec)
2. [popen](http://php.net/popen)
3. [system](http://php.net/system)
4. [exec](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
5. [pcntl_exec](http://php.net/pcntl_exec)
6. [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open)
7. [backtick (`)](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Invoking shell is not a good practice. Try to use equivalent PHP functions.

Comment: "Invoking shell is not a good practice" - well, it depends. If one is writing, say, a system administration console, then interfacing with the shell is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Check [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).